# Error deploying firebase security rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cli, firebase-security

I am trying to deploy this:

firestore.rules file:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /documents/{document} {
      // must be authenticated to view or create doc
      allow create, read: if request.auth != null;
      // must be your own doc to update
      allow update, delete: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.uid;
    }
  }
}
```

with `firebase deploy --only firestore:rules`

but I am getting an ungooglable error.

Here is my `firebase-debug.log`:

```
[debug] [2018-02-25T14:55:55.801Z] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[debug] [2018-02-25T14:55:55.803Z] Command:       /Users/swyx/.nvm/versions/node/v8.5.0/bin/node /Users/swyx/.nvm/versions/node/v8.5.0/bin/firebase deploy --only firestore:rules
[debug] [2018-02-25T14:55:55.803Z] CLI Version:   3.14.0
[debug] [2018-02-25T14:55:55.804Z] Platform:      darwin
[debug] [2018-02-25T14:55:55.804Z] Node Version:  v8.5.0
[debug] [2018-02-25T14:55:55.804Z] Time:          Sun Feb 25 2018 09:55:55 GMT-0500 (EST)
[debug] [2018-02-25T14:55:55.804Z] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[debug] 
[debug] [2018-02-25T14:55:55.818Z] > command requires scopes: ["email","openid","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"]
[debug] [2018-02-25T14:55:55.818Z] > authorizing via signed-in user
[debug] [2018-02-25T14:55:55.819Z] > refreshing access token with scopes: ["email","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase","openid"]
[debug] [2018-02-25T14:55:55.820Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST POST https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token { refresh_token: '1/redacted',
  client_id: '563584335869-redacted.apps.googleusercontent.com',
  client_secret: 'redacted',
  grant_type: 'refresh_token',
  scope: 'email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase openid' } 
 Sun Feb 25 2018 09:55:55 GMT-0500 (EST)
[debug] [2018-02-25T14:55:55.935Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[debug] [2018-02-25T14:55:55.943Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://admin.firebase.com/v1/projects/testfirepup1  
 Sun Feb 25 2018 09:55:55 GMT-0500 (EST)
[debug] [2018-02-25T14:55:56.224Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[debug] [2018-02-25T14:55:56.225Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://admin.firebase.com/v1/database/testfirepup1/tokens  
 Sun Feb 25 2018 09:55:56 GMT-0500 (EST)
[debug] [2018-02-25T14:55:56.699Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[info] 1
[info] 
[info] === Deploying to 'testfirepup1'...
[info] 
[info] i  deploying firestore
[info] i  firestore: checking firestore.rules for compilation errors...
[debug] [2018-02-25T14:55:56.917Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST POST https://firebaserules.googleapis.com/v1/projects/testfirepup1:test { source: { files: [ [Object] ] } } 
 Sun Feb 25 2018 09:55:56 GMT-0500 (EST)
[debug] [2018-02-25T14:55:57.103Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[info] ✔  firestore: rules file firestore.rules compiled successfully
[info] i  firestore: uploading rules firestore.rules...
[debug] [2018-02-25T14:55:57.105Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST POST https://firebaserules.googleapis.com/v1/projects/testfirepup1/rulesets { source: { files: [ [Object] ] } } 
 Sun Feb 25 2018 09:55:57 GMT-0500 (EST)
[debug] [2018-02-25T14:55:57.416Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[debug] [2018-02-25T14:55:57.416Z] [rules] created ruleset projects/testfirepup1/rulesets/6e8dfacc-8c69-4fd6-95b4-a28593bdb8c1
[debug] [2018-02-25T14:55:57.417Z] [rules] releasing cloud.firestore with ruleset projects/testfirepup1/rulesets/6e8dfacc-8c69-4fd6-95b4-a28593bdb8c1
[debug] [2018-02-25T14:55:57.417Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST PUT https://firebaserules.googleapis.com/v1/projects/testfirepup1/releases/cloud.firestore { name: 'projects/testfirepup1/releases/cloud.firestore',
  rulesetName: 'projects/testfirepup1/rulesets/6e8dfacc-8c69-4fd6-95b4-a28593bdb8c1' } 
 Sun Feb 25 2018 09:55:57 GMT-0500 (EST)
[debug] [2018-02-25T14:55:57.525Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 404
[debug] [2018-02-25T14:55:57.526Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE BODY <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <title>Error 404 (Not Found)!!1</title>
  <style>
    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}
  </style>
  <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>
  <p><b>404.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
  <p>The requested URL <code>/v1/projects/testfirepup1/releases/cloud.firestore</code> was not found on this server.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>

[debug] [2018-02-25T14:55:57.527Z] TypeError: Cannot create property 'error' on string '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <title>Error 404 (Not Found)!!1</title>
  <style>
    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}
  </style>
  <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>
  <p><b>404.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
  <p>The requested URL <code>/v1/projects/testfirepup1/releases/cloud.firestore</code> was not found on this server.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>
'
    at module.exports (/Users/swyx/.nvm/versions/node/v8.5.0/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/responseToError.js:11:16)
    at Request._callback (/Users/swyx/.nvm/versions/node/v8.5.0/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/api.js:43:25)
    at Request.self.callback (/Users/swyx/.nvm/versions/node/v8.5.0/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/request/request.js:186:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:213:7)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/swyx/.nvm/versions/node/v8.5.0/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/request/request.js:1163:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:210:7)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Users/swyx/.nvm/versions/node/v8.5.0/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/request/request.js:1085:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:314:30)
[error] 
[error] Error: An unexpected error has occurred.
[debug] [2018-02-25T14:56:50.487Z] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[debug] [2018-02-25T14:56:50.489Z] Command:       /Users/swyx/.nvm/versions/node/v8.5.0/bin/node /Users/swyx/.nvm/versions/node/v8.5.0/bin/firebase deploy --only firestore:rules
[debug] [2018-02-25T14:56:50.490Z] CLI Version:   3.14.0
[debug] [2018-02-25T14:56:50.490Z] Platform:      darwin
[debug] [2018-02-25T14:56:50.490Z] Node Version:  v8.5.0
[debug] [2018-02-25T14:56:50.491Z] Time:          Sun Feb 25 2018 09:56:50 GMT-0500 (EST)
[debug] [2018-02-25T14:56:50.491Z] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[debug] 
[debug] [2018-02-25T14:56:50.505Z] > command requires scopes: ["email","openid","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"]
[debug] [2018-02-25T14:56:50.505Z] > authorizing via signed-in user
[debug] [2018-02-25T14:56:50.507Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://admin.firebase.com/v1/projects/testfirepup1  
 Sun Feb 25 2018 09:56:50 GMT-0500 (EST)
[debug] [2018-02-25T14:56:51.081Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[debug] [2018-02-25T14:56:51.082Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://admin.firebase.com/v1/database/testfirepup1/tokens  
 Sun Feb 25 2018 09:56:51 GMT-0500 (EST)
[debug] [2018-02-25T14:56:51.586Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[info] 1
[info] 
[info] === Deploying to 'testfirepup1'...
[info] 
[info] i  deploying firestore
[info] i  firestore: checking firestore.rules for compilation errors...
[debug] [2018-02-25T14:56:51.847Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST POST https://firebaserules.googleapis.com/v1/projects/testfirepup1:test { source: { files: [ [Object] ] } } 
 Sun Feb 25 2018 09:56:51 GMT-0500 (EST)
[debug] [2018-02-25T14:56:52.036Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[info] ✔  firestore: rules file firestore.rules compiled successfully
[info] i  firestore: uploading rules firestore.rules...
[debug] [2018-02-25T14:56:52.038Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST POST https://firebaserules.googleapis.com/v1/projects/testfirepup1/rulesets { source: { files: [ [Object] ] } } 
 Sun Feb 25 2018 09:56:52 GMT-0500 (EST)
[debug] [2018-02-25T14:56:52.331Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[debug] [2018-02-25T14:56:52.331Z] [rules] created ruleset projects/testfirepup1/rulesets/e1d12cdc-2551-42eb-957a-25e7a9aa7bca
[debug] [2018-02-25T14:56:52.332Z] [rules] releasing cloud.firestore with ruleset projects/testfirepup1/rulesets/e1d12cdc-2551-42eb-957a-25e7a9aa7bca
[debug] [2018-02-25T14:56:52.332Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST PUT https://firebaserules.googleapis.com/v1/projects/testfirepup1/releases/cloud.firestore { name: 'projects/testfirepup1/releases/cloud.firestore',
  rulesetName: 'projects/testfirepup1/rulesets/e1d12cdc-2551-42eb-957a-25e7a9aa7bca' } 
 Sun Feb 25 2018 09:56:52 GMT-0500 (EST)
[debug] [2018-02-25T14:56:52.444Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 404
[debug] [2018-02-25T14:56:52.444Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE BODY <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <title>Error 404 (Not Found)!!1</title>
  <style>
    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}
  </style>
  <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>
  <p><b>404.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
  <p>The requested URL <code>/v1/projects/testfirepup1/releases/cloud.firestore</code> was not found on this server.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>

[debug] [2018-02-25T14:56:52.446Z] TypeError: Cannot create property 'error' on string '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <title>Error 404 (Not Found)!!1</title>
  <style>
    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}
  </style>
  <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>
  <p><b>404.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
  <p>The requested URL <code>/v1/projects/testfirepup1/releases/cloud.firestore</code> was not found on this server.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>
'
    at module.exports (/Users/swyx/.nvm/versions/node/v8.5.0/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/responseToError.js:11:16)
    at Request._callback (/Users/swyx/.nvm/versions/node/v8.5.0/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/api.js:43:25)
    at Request.self.callback (/Users/swyx/.nvm/versions/node/v8.5.0/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/request/request.js:186:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:213:7)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/swyx/.nvm/versions/node/v8.5.0/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/request/request.js:1163:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:210:7)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Users/swyx/.nvm/versions/node/v8.5.0/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/request/request.js:1085:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:314:30)
[error] 
[error] Error: An unexpected error has occurred.
```

I can't tell what's wrong so I have no idea what to fix. Please help!

Comment: The released version of `firebase-tools` is 3.17.4. You can display the version with `firebase -V`.  If you are running 3.14.0, which is the "CLI Version' shown in the log output, try updating to the latest.  Use command `npm install -g firebase-tools` in the [functions folder of your project](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started#set_up_and_initialize).

Comment: hey Bob, thank you. that solved it. if youd like to get credit for an answer i'd be happy to mark you as the answer below, but whatever it is, you have restored my somewhat damaged confidence in firebase (as well as the stackoverflow firebase community!!!!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OP indicated in a comment that the failure was the result was not having the latest version of the Firebase CLI.  To see the installed version number, use `firebase -V`.

Because features are continuously being added in new versions of the Firebase CLI, [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started#set_up_and_initialize) recommends frequently updating to ensure you have the latest version:

> In many cases, new features and bug fixes are available only with the
>   latest version of the Firebase CLI and the firebase-functions SDK.
>   It's a good practice to frequently update both the Firebase CLI and
>   the SDK with these commands inside the functions folder of your
>   Firebase project:

```
npm install firebase-functions@latest firebase-admin@latest --save
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

For reference, the Firebase CLI is open-source and is [available here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools).

Answer (score 0):

It was solved by updating the `firebase-tools` version. breaking change from 3.14 to 3.17 :( Thank you very much @bob snyder.